# Java and DOT NET client program input parameters for Restful Web Services

Tags: java, c#, web-services, rest

We have web service which was developed in java and it will accept compressed byte array in base64 format as one of the parameter.

We have created the Java client program  for testing program and it is working fine.

We would like to create similar client program in DOT NET also.But we are unable to create base64 format with byte array compression as we have done in java programming language.

Please suggest me what is the best suitable compression method for byte array object for both java and .net(c#).

Comment: _"we are unable to create base64 format with byte array compression [in .Net]"_ - why not? What exotic compression algorithm are you using?

Comment: Do you mean like [`Convert.ToBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Convert.FromBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx), or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: we are using Deflater for compression and inflater for decompression. I have followed the below link.                                                                         http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/243808-compression-and-decompression-between-java-and-c%23/

Comment: I need code for decompressing byte array object in java. But it should be  able to do decompression in java  with compressed byte array and dot net compressed byte array also.